# onOptionsItemSelected confusion

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

something strange happens in my method, for some reason I can not access my ID menu item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
         android:id="@+id/menu"
         android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
         android:showAsAction="always"
         android:title="Buscar">
    </item>
</menu>
```

Method :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    SessionManager manager = new SessionManager();
    System.out.println("ID"+item.getItemId());
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case  2131361981:
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Importante")
            .setMessage("¿Está seguro de validar todas las inscripciones")
            .setPositiveButton("Validar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    SessionManager manager = new SessionManager();
                    //code
                }
             })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 

                }
             })
             .show();
        break;

    }
    return true;
}
```

As you can see, I can print the ID of the element to which you clicked is that number `2131361981` but if I try to log `R.id.menu` not exist.

Build the project again, clean but nothing, I can not access that item and I have no idea why. This stop working, but it is not the right way it has to be

Comment: Is this an import problem? Resources are compiled into the same package as your manifest specifies. If you create an Activity in a different package, you need to add an import statement for the resources (like import com.my.package.R;) to access them.

Comment: @adelphus Very clear that! but does not work, it is in the right package.